# Preventing Multiple Read-Through in Cache

Tags: c#, caching

We have a caching class that allows for a read through pseudo code is below

```
GetItemFromCache()

if (GetItemFromCache != true)
{
    ReadThrough();
}
```

If multiple calls hit the cache with the same key at the same time, I could do multiple ReadThrough, which are potentially costly (trip to service across network). I would like to be able to block on the read through and only allow a single read through.

I think that adding a lock around the read through would work as long as the lock is unique to the cache key. I could handle that via a dictionary that contains Dictionary. I'm just not 100% convinced that this is the best solution to solving the issue, or if something else would be a better idea.

Comment: You've listed out 3 different possible performance dimensions:
1) Optimizing throughput to the cache service
2) Optimizing the execution time of each individual thread
3) Optimizing the net throughput of all threads
Clearly identifying your goal helps narrow down the best solution.